# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException on DataSource/DataList

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm relatively new, so it shouldn't be too surprising I haven't seen the error before, but when I try to run a page, I get the error  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Here is the code for that page:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Docs] WHERE Section = 1">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Docs] WHERE Section = 2">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource3" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Docs] WHERE Section = 3">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource4" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Docs] WHERE Section = 4">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<h2>Benefits Information</h2>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="OpenEnrollmentHeader" runat="server" Text="Open Enrollment" CssClass="BenefitsHeaderStyle" />
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="10" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="OpenEnrollmentDocs" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Label") %>'
        NavigateUrl='<%# "~/docs/HRDocs/" & Eval("Filename") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<br />
```

I can see that it must have something to do with my data sources or the Datalist control, but I have no idea what. Any ideas? I can tell you that there is one result in the first select statement and none, perhaps, in the others.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a reserved word, ill try and pick it out now

Comment: You can see (barely) that I'm using VB because of my "&" in the NavigateURL property.

Comment: in this list somewhere, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t(v=vs.90).aspx